# Output of map of set custom objects c++

Tags: c++, dictionary, collections, set

So I have a map that has user defined keys and the values in it are sets of objects too. So I'm trying to write some print function but I have no idea how to do that. (I'm kind of new to maps and sets).
My problem function:

```cpp
void print() const 
    {
        for (auto& itr : my_mmap)
        {
            std::cout << "Key for this set:" << itr.first << "\n\n";
            for (int i = 0; i< itr.second.size(); i++)
            {
                std::cout << itr.second[i] << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here's my class:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
#include <set>

class Enclosing {
private:
    class Key {
        int m_number;
        std::string m_name;
    public:
        Key(int num, std::string name) :m_number(num), m_name(std::move(name)) {};

        bool operator<(const Key& rhs) const {
            return std::tie(m_number, m_name) < std::tie(rhs.m_number, rhs.m_name);
        }

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Key& k) {
            return os << '{' << k.m_number << ',' << k.m_name << '}';
        }
    };

    class Nested {
        std::string m_str;
        double m_dbl;
        bool m_boolean;
    public:
        Nested(std::string str, double dbl, bool boolean) :m_str(std::move(str)), m_dbl(dbl), m_boolean(boolean) {};

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Nested& n) {
            return os << '{' << n.m_str << ',' << n.m_dbl << ',' << n.m_boolean << '}';
        }
    };

    std::multimap<Key, std::set<Nested>> my_mmap;

public:
    template <class... Args>
    void add_new_object_to_mmap(Args&&... args) {
        my_mmap.emplace(std::piecewise_construct, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
/*
THAT PROBLEM FUNCTION
*/
    void print() const 
    {
        for (auto& itr : my_mmap)
        {
            std::cout << "Key for this set:" << itr.first << "\n\n";
            for (int i = 0; i< itr.second.size(); i++)
            {
                std::cout << itr.second[i] << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
    static Enclosing& get_singleton() {
        static Enclosing instance;
        return instance;
    }
};

}
```

**So the problem is that I am getting an error "no operator "[]" match these operands". How can I output my map and set in the best way?**

Comment: You didn't even ask a question nor have mentioned what problem you did encounter. If you have an error message, include it in the question (it often tells the answer). If you don't get the desired output then please state what you get and what you expected instead.

Comment: Yeah, thank you for your comment. I'm going to edit my question right now =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **problem** is that we cannot use **indexing** on a `std::set`. Thus `itr.second[i]` is not valid because `itr.second` is an `std::set`.

To solve this you can use a range-based `for` loop as shown below:

```
for (const auto&elem:itr.second)
{
     std::cout << elem << std::endl;
}
```